# Prevent Backbone.history.navigate from decoding URL fragment

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, url-encoding

I'm triggering Backbone's navigate function to change the URL after an event fires.

**Code**

`Backbone.history.navigate("?q=" + encodeURIComponent(searchQuery))`

In my case, `searchQuery` could be something like *max müller*, thus containing spaces and unicode characters. That's why I have to encode it with `encodeURIComponent` into *max+m%C3%BCller*.

**But within Backbones navigate function, my `searchQuery` is beeing decoded back to "max müller" and returned like that.**

So at the end the URL gets changed into

> myroot.com/?q=max müller

which is not a valid URL. Instead it should be like this:

> myroot.com/?q=max+m%C3%BCller

As far as I can think, there are two possible ways to solve this:

```
 1. changing/extending Backbone.history.navigate to return the encoded
    fragment

 2. recreating Backbone's navigate functionality to change the URL with plain Javascript or using any other library
```

But why isn't it Backbone's default behaviour? It doesn't make sense to create an invalid URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the answer to this while looking at the backbone js source code:

https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1817

Basically in order to match the url to your routes you need to decode the url. It kinda makes sense as you wouldn't want url encoded routes in your code - though that doesn't really help you sadly.

I suspect extending would be the most sensible thing to do

Comment: Although extending the core would be the best thing to do, as you said, I decided for the moment to use plain javascript and did like this: `window.location.hash = "?q=" + encodeURIComponent(searchQuery);`.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense :)